# Trying to get a simple php form to fire

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I shouldnt even be in HTML/CSS, but here I am trying to incorporate a php modal contact form into my site...

I'm trying to get all of a demo form's functionality into my footer page (and then I'll restyle everything.)

http://danux.me/sections/footer_modal.html

I'm trying to get "email me" to fire ideally, but am settling now for just the Demo button to fire the popup form.

I also uploaded the demo form I'm pulling code from, just to make sure it works on my site. (It does.)

http://danux.me/contact/

Any guesses as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what good will it do us by visiting your website? A: not much; not for the "php" part anyway to which you tagged as.

Comment: can you be clearer in what you expect to happen and what does not happen? The email link doesnt have any action (href or javascript) bound.

Comment: Im trying to get http://danux.me/sections/footer_modal.html to have an overlay and modal pop up like http://danux.me/contact/.  I am not sure how to add the php, the js, css, jquery all to this page (or didn't know php wasn't inspectable). There are broken links on the page, but none of the broken images are significant. Just the demo button. I'm not expecting the form to work yet, but just trying to get the popup action to work like the demo link http://danux.me/contact/

Comment: here's your problem: `GET http://danux.me/sections/data/contact.php 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. That's very helpful as I don't know anything about inspecting php. (not being sarcastic.) So I need to find in the demo where that appears and add it to my http://danux.me/sections/footer_modal.html  I knew something was missing...

Comment: first demo is in different folder. So `$.get` to 'data/contact.php' will fail. You'd have to change the url there to `../contact/data/contact.php`.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, Jeff. I just found a few in the JS files too.

Comment: That was it. Thanks, Jeff!!! (I thought the JS was just for the form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first link is in a different folder, yet the url for `$.get` points to the same *relative* file. Which isn't there.

So in contact.js needs to have

```
 $.get("../contact/data/contact.php", function(data){
```

I obviously cant test this. And it looks like there is some redesign in folderstructure coming up.

Comment: That makes sense Jeff. I'd wanted to just get as far as you got me, so I can style, do the whole thing again to attach to my index.html, and then apply the edits from the developer's documentation. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction what paths need to be adjusted.